# Tool window quick access doesn't work in IntelliJ IDEA Sometimes

Tags: intellij-idea

I'am Using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 (Ultimate Edition)

I've been going through all the documents from `JetBrains`, but I couldn't find how to show my `tool windows`. Sometimes IDEA behaves unexpectedly by **not** giving me a way to show my `tool windows`. I've tried to access them using my usual *keyboard shortcuts*,  *Find action feature* or by clicking this icon [image: If you hover the mouse cursor over this button, a menu opens that provides quick access to tool windows.]

But unfortunately, IDEA does not give me any response.

By the way, it works If I completely shutdown IDEA, but I can't do that when I am in the middle of a keynote since it takes time to reboot.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Do you get any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in..."). As a workaround you may set them visible permanently ("View | Tool Buttons")

Comment: I didn't get any errors in the log. I prefer to let them invisible and invoke them by predefined shortcuts. By the way, this issue occurs 2-3 times a week. I want to solve it without rebooting IDEA.

Comment: Are they shown if you use "View | Tool Windows | ..."?

Comment: @y.bedrov No, I wasn't able to access them using "View | Tool Windows | ..."

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack attaching logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.